# Bash loop only processing every other file

Tags: bash, loops

I've been working on a script to generate .tbn files for my home videos. If I run the script, it only seems to process every other file.

```
#!/bin/bash

find ~/Movies/Home\ Movies/Canada\ Trip -type f | egrep '\.mp4$|\.avi$|\.mkv$' | while read file ; do

    if [ ! -f "${file:0:${#file}-3}tbn" ]; then
        # .tbn not found
        echo "$file"
        ffmpeg  -itsoffset -13  -i "$file" -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -s 400x224 -an -f rawvideo "${file:0:${#file}-3}tbn"
    fi

done
```

And here is my data set:

```
Canada.Trip.S01E01.avi
Canada.Trip.S01E02.avi
Canada.Trip.S01E03.avi
Canada.Trip.S01E04.avi
Canada.Trip.S01E05.avi
Canada.Trip.S01E06.avi
Canada.Trip.S01E07.avi
Canada.Trip.S01E08.avi
Canada.Trip.S01E09.avi
Canada.Trip.S01E10.avi
Canada.Trip.S01E11.avi
Canada.Trip.S01E12.avi
Canada.Trip.S01E13.avi
Canada.Trip.S01E14.mp4
Canada.Trip.S01E15.mp4
Canada.Trip.S01E16.mp4
Canada.Trip.S01E17.mp4
Canada.Trip.S01E18.avi
Canada.Trip.S01E19.mkv
Canada.Trip.S01E20.mp4
```

So the first time I run it, it generates tbn's for 1,3,5,7 etc.. The even numbered files fail with `vies/Canada Trip/Canada.Trip.S01E16.mp4: No such file or directory`
 (note the truncated start of the file name)

If I run the script again it generates the even numbered files .tbn files. I've never used Bash before so I'm finding the whole situation confusing!

Comment: Your script works fine for me. Can you post the output of:
find ~/Movies/Home\ Movies/Canada\ Trip -type f | egrep '\.mp4$|\.avi$|\.mkv$'

Comment: You don't need to use `egrep`: `find ~/Movies/Home\ Movies/Canada\ Trip -type f \( '*.mp4' -o '*.avi' -o '*.mkv' \)` or `find ~/Movies/Home\ Movies/Canada\ Trip -type f -regex '.*\.\(mp4\|avi\|mkv\)'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ffmpeg [reads stdin](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/089). Also, you should always use `read -r`.